# nsnotification for uiwebview did finishloading

Tags: ios4

How can I register nsnotificatiiom for uiwebview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to set a notification, just use the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate

Comment: The reason I am trying use NSNotification is because I am assigning a delegate to the content of the webview

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do? Are you subclassing `UIWebView`? Could you post some sample code, if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a notification. Use the delegate's method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.